# How to re render in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I re-render a functional component in React Native?

I've seen only the option of using `this.forceUpdate()` but it doesn't work with functional components.

Comment: I feel like there's a misunderstanding of React's way of doing things at play. You shouldn't have to force a re-render in the vast majority of cases. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third party library called [use-force-update](https://github.com/CharlesStover/use-force-update)

Here is an example code below:

```js
import useForceUpdate from 'use-force-update';

const MyButton = () => {

  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    alert('I will re-render now.');
    forceUpdate();
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a force re-render. For a functional component do something like this. Create a re-render state that you update whenever you need the component to re-render

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Jira = (props) => {
  const [rerender, setrerender] = useState(0)


  function dosomething() {
    setrerender(rerender+1)
  }

  console.log("rerender")

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={dosomething}>
      </button>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Jira;
```